# Change SplashScreen When OnLunch method has async keyword

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I want to change my splash screen when my program update its database. everything is fine until I change OnLunch event handler. I must use `async` keyword based on some conditions.

```
protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
     bool IsAppUpdated = await CheckDbVersion();
     if(IsAppUpdated)
     {
        if (args.PreviousExecutionState != ApplicationExecutionState.Running)
        {
            bool loadState = (args.PreviousExecutionState == ApplicationExecutionState.Terminated);
            SplashScreenExtend extendedSplash = new SplashScreenExtend(args.SplashScreen, loadState);
            Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
        }
        bool fine = await ReconstructDatabase();
     }
       //doing sth else

}
```

the problem is when  I run the program the new splash-screen doesn't appear. but when I debug the code the splash-screen appears. in addition, when I remove async keyword and await functions every becomes ok.

please advice me where is my mistake.

Comment: MSDN has an article dedicated to this topic [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh868191(v=win.10).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so what is happening here is this: The `OnLaunched` event is completing before the splash screen has a chance to load, because it is `async void`. This means that the method that calls `OnLaunched` fires, then just continues without waiting for a response. In Debug, the speed that calling method passes over `OnLaunched` is likely delayed due to the debugger having to load the symbols for all of the modules, making it successfully change the splash screen before you get a chance to see it. Unfortunately, you can't change it to what it needs to be, `async Task`, because that would a) change the signature of the method so it won't be overridden and b) the calling method likely still does not `await` it, so the same issue will occur.

What this means for you is: You can't `await` methods in `OnLaunched`. This means that either a) you will have to do the proper `await`ing in your `SplashScreenExtend` class or run the `CheckDbVersion` and `ReconstructDatabase` methods synchronously (unless you can 'set-and-forget' `ReconstructDatabase`, in which case you can still run it `async`, but you just can't `await` it).

Hope this helps and happy coding.

Comment: "You can't await methods in OnLaunched"...why not?

Answer (score 0):

You must activate the current window after setting the windows content to show the splashscreen.

```
SplashScreenExtend extendedSplash = new  SplashScreenExtend(args.SplashScreen, loadState);
Window.Current.Content = extendedSplash;
Window.Current.Activate();
```